# (Fluent)Validation in models that contain child models

Tags: catel

In our current catel application we have a ModelBase class that has a member that is another ModelBase.

We want to use the fluentvalidation extention to write our validation rules for both models.

e.g.
Models:

```
public class Model : ModelBase
{
    public Model()
    {
        ChildModel = new ChildModel();
    }

    public string FirstName
    {
        get { return GetValue<string>(FirstNameProperty); }
        set { SetValue(FirstNameProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly PropertyData FirstNameProperty = RegisterProperty("FirstName", typeof(string), string.Empty);

    public ChildModel ChildModel
    {
        get { return GetValue<ChildModel>(ChildModelProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ChildModelProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly PropertyData ChildModelProperty = RegisterProperty("ChildModel", typeof(ChildModel), null);
}

public class ChildModel : ModelBase
{
    public static readonly PropertyData TestStringProperty = RegisterProperty("TestString", typeof(string), null);

    public string TestString
    {
        get { return GetValue<string>(TestStringProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TestStringProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

Validators:

```
public class PersonValidator : AbstractValidator<ModelWithoutValidation>
{
    public PersonValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(model => model.FirstName)
            .NotNull()
            .NotEmpty();

        RuleFor(model => model.MiddleName)
            .NotNull()
            .NotEmpty();

        RuleFor(model => model.LastName)
            .NotNull()
            .NotEmpty()
            .WithMessage("Last name cannot be empty");

        //this doesnt work, so we use a second validator for the ChildModel
        //RuleFor(model => model.ChildModel.TestString)
        //    .NotNull()
        //    .Length(2, 10)
        //    .When(model => model.ChildModel != null);
    }
}

public class ChildValidator : AbstractValidator<ChildModel>
{
    public ChildValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(model => model.TestString)
            .NotNull()
            .NotEmpty()
            .Length(2, 10);
    }
}
```

The parent model should only be valid if all of its child models are valid too, is there a way to do this?

Also, the InfoBarMessageControl only shows the error of the parent properties in the parent control even though the control that is bound to the child model property (TestString) shows that there is an error.

[image: InfoBarMessageControlFault]

It updates to show that there is an error after the property of the child model changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the parent, you should loop your child models and validate them manually. There is no way in Catel to automatically do hierarchical validation and expose this through the `IDataErrorInfo` interface.

You can create an `IValidationContext` object though that contains all the validation inside a single context.